# How to load a new screen in the same Tab view?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Screen which contains two tab bars. Out of which one Tab bar view has button inside it. I want to load a new screen in the same tab view on button click.

In the image attached you can see a button.
 [On clicking Go to Details button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FubX7.png) I want to load details Page in the the same tab bar view.

Comment: Why do you want to load it in the same tab? The usual thing to do is to navigate to another page and then return to the tab when the user has seen the details page. If you really want to stay in the same tab then you probably need to pop up a dialogue or use the bottom sheet feature...but really, if the details are extensive you should just show them in another page.

Comment: My requirement demands such a scenario. what to do. I solved the issue, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Full example on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/0dedba766e2a1fec8241a7ba81b1abc2)

```
TabBarView(children: [
  Navigator(
      onGenerateRoute: (settings) => MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => YourContent(),
      ),
    )
])
```

Comment: She  has a button in her image, so your answer does not apply.

Comment: Missed that, apologies. I shouldn't check this stuff on my phone :-(

Comment: Hey thanks for the solution. I resolved this issue by creating an enum and calling different containers depending on the state defined in the enum.

Comment: ht,how to  navigate to full screen with your code? i want navigate page to same tab and navigate to page ,full screen,how is it?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setState((){})` to reveal data on screen but you cannot navigate to other screen only inside one tabbar view.

You can use `Navigate.pushNamed()` to navigate to other screen.